# How do I create a virtual file?

Tags: import, files-and-directories

How do I present a string as a virtual text file (without actually writing the string to a file), that can be read by functions awaiting a local file (or URL) as an input?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImportString.html

Comment: Additionally, there is `StringToStream`? Many file-related function will accept a stream instead of a filename. You probably want to give more details about what exatcly you try to do and why...

Comment: Thank you @Albert, `StringToStream` was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As george2079 mentioned there is `ImportString` which lets you directly import data from a string representing a file content.

A more general approach is to use `StringToStream` which returns a `Stream` object. `Stream`s can be used in many  file-related functions instead of a filename. You can then scan through your string e.g. line by line with functions like `ReadLine` or `ReadList`. [Low Level File Operations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LowLevelFileOperations.html) gives an overview of functions which are candidates to work with `Streams`.